# Oracle: How fill in the gaps between rows using previous next row's values using sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the table:

```
id  year    quarter total
==  ====    ======= =====
1   2010    1       100
1   2010    2       0
1   2010    3       100
1   2010    4       100
2   2010    1       20
2   2010    2       20
2   2010    3       20
2   2010    4       20
```

How fill in the gaps between rows using previous next row's values in Oracle to get the following output:

```
id  year    quarter total
==  ====    ======= =====
1   2010    1       100
1   2010    2       100
1   2010    3       100
1   2010    4       100
2   2010    1       20
2   2010    2       20
2   2010    3       20
2   2010    4       20
```

the values of previous and next columns should be the same to fill the rows.

Comment: What is the "previous next row's values"?

Comment: What do you do if you have two zeros in a row? grab the most recent non-zero value? Or at most go back one row?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: 100 should be the next value

Comment: @Michael Broughton in this case, we should go back one row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all rows to be the same for a given `year` and `id`, just use `max()`:

```
select t.*,
       max(total) over (partition by year, id) as imputed_total
from t;
```

There seems to be no need for conditional logic.  You could just do:

```
select t.id, t.year, t.quarter,
       max(total) over (partition by year, id) as imputed_total
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select 
    id, 
    year, 
    quarter, 
    case 
        when 
            total = 0 
            and lag(total) over(partition by id order by year, quarter) 
                = lead(total) over(partition by id order by year, quarter) 
        then lag(total) over(partition by id order by year, quarter)
        else total
    end total
from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE Tablename
SET total = 100
WHERE id = 1 AND QUARTER = 2;

Comment: I think Sandro looks for a generic answer, not a solution for this specific example.

Comment: I just use the KISS principle LOL

Answer (score 0):

You can use range with an analytical function. Will also work with avg()

```
select 
    id, 
    year, 
    quarter, 
    case 
        when 
            total = 0 then
            max(total) over (partition by id order by year,quarter RANGE BETWEEN 1 preceding and 1 following) 
        else total
    end total
from mytable
```